# Girth line equation of Breather

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, curves, parametrization

How to find equation of the central shape at  $(u=0)$ for the [Breather](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfnOd.png) in central plane normal to its axis of polar symmetry?

The Breather is not a surface of revolution.

It is required to find central angle subtended for a segment or the equation whose roots supply ridges /cusps / vertices in the equator/central  plane for given $b$. Trying to plot/visualize some regular spiked curved polygons.

Setting $u=0$ results  generally in self-intersecting central profiles not periodic in $v,$ ***except***  so far found $(b,n)$ combinations (by trial & error) pictured:

Please help in simplifications with a view to find how $b$ or $w$ determines formation of central sections with integral number $n$ of cusps/spikes.

[image: Covid19_like Cuspy Merdns]

Answer (score 0):

Just set $u=0$ and eliminate the range of u variable:

```
r := 1 - b^2;
w := Sqrt[r];
u := 0;
denom := b*((w*Cosh[b*u])^2 + (b*Sin[w*v])^2);
breather = {-u + (2*r*Cosh[b*u]*Sinh[b*u])/
     denom, (2*w*Cosh[b*u]*(-(w*Cos[v]*Cos[w*v]) - Sin[v]*Sin[w*v]))/
    denom, (2*w*Cosh[b*u]*(-(w*Sin[v]*Cos[w*v]) + Cos[v]*Sin[w*v]))/
    denom};
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[breather /. b -> 0.4],
 {v, -37.4, 37.4},
 PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.02]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, did that. Just trying to find inter-cusp angle subtended at center as a function of $b$.In general they may not be always as regular as you have pictured.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have accidentally edited-out the link to the definition of the [Breather surface (via xahlee.info)](http://xahlee.info/surface/breather_p/breather_p.html). For completeness and clarity, here's a formatted version of the parameterization (with parameters $u$ and $v$):
$$\begin{align}
x &= -u + \frac{r\sinh 2bu}{\delta} \\
y &= \phantom{-u+\;}\frac{2 w \cosh bu (-w \cos v \cos wv - \sin v\sin wv)}{\delta} \\ 
z &= \phantom{-u+\;}\frac{2w\cosh bu (- w\sin v \cos wv + \cos v \sin wv)}{\delta}
\end{align} \tag{1}$$
where $b$ varies from $0$ to $1$, $r := 1-b^2$, $w := \sqrt{r}$, and $\delta := b \left( w^2 \cosh^2b u + b^2\sin^2w v \right)$. I don't know why the author didn't define, say, $b := \cos\beta$, $r := \sin^2\beta$, $w := \sin\beta$; I'll pepper these in when convenient.

When $u=0$, we have
$$\delta = \cos\beta \left( \sin^2\beta + \cos^2\beta\sin^2wv \right)
= \cos\beta \left( 1 - \cos^2\beta\cos^2wv \right) \tag{2}$$
and
$$(x,y,z) = \frac{2\sin\beta}{\delta}\left(0,-w \cos v \cos wv - \sin v\sin wv,
- w\sin v \cos wv + \cos v \sin wv \right)\tag{3}$$

In the $yz$-plane, we therefore find
$$y^2 + z^2 = \frac{4\sin^2\beta (w^2\cos^2 wv + \sin^2 wv)}{\cos^2\beta(1-\cos^2\beta\cos^2wv)^2} = \frac{4\tan^2\beta}{1-\cos^2\beta\cos^2(v\sin\beta)} \tag{4}$$

If the girth curve is periodically scalloped, we would expect $(5)$ to periodically reach a minimum. Clearly, these minima occur when
$$\cos(v\sin\beta) = 0 \quad\to\quad v = \frac{k\pi}{2\sin\beta} \;, k\in\mathbb{Z} \tag{5}$$
The corresponding "polar angles" $\theta_k$ for these minima are given by
$$\begin{align}
\tan\theta_k = \frac{y}{z} &= \frac{ w \cos v \cos wv + \sin v\sin wv}{
w\sin v \cos wv - \cos v \sin wv} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{ w \cos v \cos\frac{k\pi}{2} + \sin v\sin\frac{k\pi}{2}}{
w \sin v \cos\frac{k\pi}{2} - \cos v \sin\frac{k\pi}{2}} \\[6pt]
&= \begin{cases}
\phantom{-}\cot v, & k \;\text{even} \\
-\tan v, & k \;\text{odd}
\end{cases}
\end{align} \tag{6}$$
So that
$$\theta_k = \begin{cases}
\dfrac\pi2-\dfrac{k\pi}{2\sin\beta}, & k \;\text{even} \\[4pt]
\phantom{\dfrac\pi2}-\dfrac{k\pi}{2\sin\beta}, & k \;\text{odd}
\end{cases} \quad\bmod \pi \tag{7}$$

Since we're reducing *modulo* $\pi$, it isn't necessarily the case that the $\theta_k$ for consecutive $k$ correspond to consecutive scallops. It's clear that the periodic nature of the girth curve requires $\pi/2/\sin\beta$ to be a rational multiple of $\pi$; that is, we require $\sin\beta$ to be rational, and the evident period of the girth curve should be dictated by (a multiple of) the numerator of $\sin\beta$. (I'm being a little loose here because my brain is tired.)

In OP's second and third examples, we have
$$\begin{align}
b &= \cos\beta = \frac35 \quad\to\quad \sin\beta = \frac45 \qquad 8\text{-fold symmetry} \tag{8}\\[4pt]
b &= \cos\beta = \frac45 \quad\to\quad \sin\beta = \frac35 \qquad 3\text{-fold symmetry} \tag{9}
\end{align}$$
For the first example, things are not quite so exact:
$$b = \cos\beta = 0.4 \quad\to\quad \sin\beta = 0.9165\ldots \approx\frac{11}{12} \qquad \text{not truly}\; 22\text{-fold symmetry} \tag{10}$$
I'm not sure of the proper way to reconcile the fourth example. I'll leave further consideration to the reader.

Comment: So fine this !!.. perhaps a comprehensive girth relation as a function of $\beta$ for odd/even scallops is just round the corner.. so that cases like $  n\in\mathbb{Z} = 11, 12 ,.. 17,18 $ etc can be a priori computed and checked with later verified polar plots. I too  like the trig look rather than $\sqrt{1- w^2}$ etc., everytime appearing inside the arguments. Shall report further work on this.  Regards.